# Where to find an original Android image?

Tags: custom-roms, nexus-one

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Where can I find stock or custom ROMs for my Android device?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/17152/where-can-i-find-stock-or-custom-roms-for-my-android-device)

I have found many custom ROMs for download. But now I want to use the official ROM for my phone. Is there any way to do it without a NAndroid backup?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Download ROM Manager and go to the "Stock Images" section of "Download ROMs".

You should always do a Nandroid backup when messing with system files. There's always a risk of something going wrong. Also when installing new ROMs (whether custom or stock), it's recommended that you do a clean wipe of the system before installing.

Comment: Note that usually you only need to wipe when switching Android versions. This differs per ROM though.

Comment: Many times it would be safe to just install over your current installations. But I've personally had issues when installing one 2.2 ROM  (Sapphire) over another (Bugless Beast)